# Library for 2D (possibly 3D) ray tracing like visualization of interior structure

Tags: library, c#, data-visualization, drawing, opengl

I am currently working on a visualization model for the interior of a complex piping system. The model is used to visualize the reflection of waves which are introduced into the pipe, so it will involve some (simple) form of ray tracing.

I am hoping to start with a 2D cross section (within a given region) and display the geometry of the wave reflections, before moving on to a (possibly) 3D interior view of the entire pipe.

This visualization does not have to be real time; I only require a static display of it. I am currently working in c#, and understand that there are standard frameworks out there for visualization (e.g. OpenGL, OpenCL, etc.)

I am quite new to programmatic visualizations, so would like to ask, if there is an open-source platform, that is best recommended for my needs? I have thought of using the native drawing functions in c#, but realized that it may be cumbersome (or impossible), should I ever move on to 3D.

Comment: Take a look at Blender http://www.blender.org/